# Angle between chords joining midpoints of four arcs on a circle always $90$ degrees?

Tags: geometry

> Let $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be the midpoints of arcs $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$, $\stackrel{\frown}{BC}$, $\stackrel{\frown}{CD}$, $\stackrel{\frown}{DA}$, respectively. Show that the chords $WY$ and $XZ$ are perpendicular.

So I know the rule that says that if $O$ were the center then $\angle AOB$ would equal $\frac{1}{2}$ the arc $\stackrel{\frown}{AWB}$. However, I don't know how to use this or even if I should to solve this problem. Some direction would be great!

Comment: There's related rule that says that chords $\overline{PQ}$ and $\overline{RS}$ make an angle whose measure is $\frac12( \stackrel{\frown}{PR} + \stackrel{\frown}{QS} )$.

Comment: is there not another way to prove this?

Comment: The rule I mention can be proven using the rule you mention; they're usually taught together. In this case, "my" rule proves the result pretty immediately. There are certainly other approaches, though.

Answer (score 1):

A generalization of the Inscribed Angle Theorem ("The measure of an inscribed angle is half the measure of the subtended arc.") states that the measure of an angle formed by lines meeting at an interior point is *half of the sum* of the measures of opposing subtended arcs. (For lines meeting at an *exterior* point, it's *half of the difference*.)

For instance, considering chords $WX$ and $YZ$ in this diagram ...

[image]

... we have:

$$\angle WPX = \frac{1}{2}\left(\;\stackrel{\frown}{WX} + \stackrel{\frown}{YZ}\; \right) = \angle YPZ \quad\text{and}\quad
\angle XPY = \frac{1}{2}\left(\;\stackrel{\frown}{XY} + \stackrel{\frown}{ZW}\; \right) = \angle ZPW$$

Note that this proves the OP's result immediately. If $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ bisect arcs between points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and if we assign arc measures $w$, $x$, $y$, $z$ as shown, then all four angles at $P$ have measure 
$$\frac{1}{2}(\;w+x+y+z\;)$$
which is necessarily $90^\circ$.